# getApplicationContext() on Universal Image Gallery is Undefined?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am trying to load some images from the array and the following is my schedule adapter.
Just getting undefined context. Not sure what to do ?
Also no images are being loaded

```
public class Schedule_ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity activity;
private final String[] name, category, image;
Typeface colab, colab_bold, Bebas;
int selected = -1;

public Schedule_ArrayAdapter(Activity activity, String[] name, String[] category, String[] image) {
    super(activity, R.layout.schedule_item, category);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
    this.image = image;

    this.colab = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "ColabThi.otf");
    this.colab_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "ColabMed.otf");
    this.colab_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "BebasNeue.otf");
//  ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .threadPoolSize(5)
    .enableLogging()
    .build();

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .build();

    ImageLoader imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `activity.getApplicationContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Your current class inherits from ArrayAdapter, which is not a subclass of Context. The `getApplicationContext()` method is only available in classes inheriting from Context, like `Activities`, `Services` and `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: When I use activity.getApplicationContext() , it says the blank field may have not been initalized. It is referring to Activity activity. And asking me to remove the final . So from private final Activity activity; to private Activity activity;

Comment: @Sam You will have to remove final. When you declare something as final, it means you cannot alter the value after its creation, so it won't get assigned.

Comment: Removing Final gives me a null pointer exception on that line. I think that though might be altogether a different problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving a valid Activity instance?

Comment: yes it is receiving a Valid activity instance. I think there is some issue with my code that should set the images in the adapter.

Comment: I have updated the full code above can you have a look please ?

Comment: Post the code where you create and use an instance of `Schedule_ArrayAdapter`

Comment: ok I have updated the secondary code. You can see how I use the adapter after fetching the JSON values.

Comment: here is the pastbin http://pastebin.com/aXjW15GC. The line is 26 in Schedule_Arrayadapter

Comment: added the xml as well for you to have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways. If it too much to ask I might open another thread about this.

Comment: @Sam hmm. I can't see anything wrong here. You might have better luck with someone else if you open another thread though